# Move a vertex along a plane, given the plane normal

Tags: python, numpy, math, 3d

I have a 3D vector and a 3D face normal. How do I go along to move this vector along the given face normal using Python (with or without numpy)?

Ideally, I'd build a matrix using the face normal with the `x` and `y` and multiply it by the original vector or something like that, but I can't get my head around on how to build it. It's been a while since Linear Algebra.

EDIT:

Thanks for pointing out that my question was too broad.

My goal is to get a new point, that is `x` and `y` units away from the original point, along the face defined by its normal.

Example: If the point is `(0,0,0)` and the normal is `(0, 0, 1)`, the result would be `(x, y, 0)`.

Example 2: If the point is `(1, 0, 0)` and the normal is `(0, 1, 0)`, the result would be `(1+x, 0, y)`.

I'd need to extrapolate that to work with any `point`, `normal`, `x` and `y`.

Comment: Matrices are probably a bit overkill. Just find a vector that is orthogonal to the normal (there are infinitely many) and add that to your point position. For more specific help, your question needs to be more specific. But it is probably better suited for [math.se], anyway.

Comment: What does *`x` and `y` units away* mean? Two points can only have one distance. If you mean two distances along two distinct directions, then you need to define those directions. A normal alone is not enough (you could rotate arbitrarily about the normal).

Comment: Oh! That makes sense, @NicoSchertler. There's no way to know where `x` and `y` would go... I'd need more information for that. Thanks.

Comment: You need to define a *coordinate system* in the plane, i.e. the directions of increasing X and Y parameter. The example you provided was too trivial - these directions just happen to be the X and Y axes. But in a more general context (i.e. different normal direction) this would not be applicable

Answer (score 2):

[The projection](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/633243/26324) of a `vector` to a plane defined by its `normal` is:

```
def projection(vector, normal):
    return vector - vector.dot(normal) * normal
```

Presumably this means you want something like:

```
x + projection(y, normal)
```

Comment: Hi, Andy! I probably should have written more. I have a 3d point in space and a 3d normal vector of a face. I want a new point `x` and `y` units away from the original point, along the face defined by the normal.

Comment: @SergioMoura sounds like you need to the add the projection to the original vector, but yeah your x and y may well be different.

Answer (score -1):

```
def give_me_a_new_vertex_position_along_normal(old_vertex_position, normal):
  new_vertex_position = old_vertex_position + normal
  return new_vertex_position
```

There is a difference between affine spaces (your normals) and euclidean/linear spaces (your vertices).

Vectors in linear space have coordinates associated with them, while vectors in affine space do not.

Adding an affine-spaced vector to a linear-spaced vector is called projection and that is what you are looking to do.

Comment: Your function name needs underscores between words and so do your variable names. This is completely illegible.